# Can't Get PSExec to work with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Last week I developed a script that would check if psremoting was enabled on specified machines. This week I began working on a script that would enable psremoting on specified machines but I can't get psexec to run in powershell (Also, yes I know psremoting can be enabled through group policy). Here is my script:

```
$input = Read-Host @"
Select Option
(1)Manually enter computer(s)
(2)Retrieve computer(s) from file

Option
"@

If ($input -eq 1){
    $count = Read-Host "How many computers"
    $Computers = 1..$count
    $b=0;$c=1; ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {$Computers[$b] = Read-Host "Computer" $c; $b++; $c++}
} ElseIF ($input-eq 2) {
    $Computers = Read-Host "File" 
    $Computers = Get-Content $Computers
} Else {
    write-host "Invalid Option"
    Exit
}

cls
$User = Read-Host "Enter username"
$Pass = Read-Host "Enter password"
cls

$PSExec = "C:\Windows\System32\PSExec\PSExec.exe"

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){

# & $PSExec \\$Computer -u $User -p $Pass -h -c "C:\Temp\mybat.bat"
& $PSExec \\$Computer -u $User -p $Pass "ipconfig"

}
```

I get the following error when executing script:

> PSExec.exe : 
>   At C:\MyStuff\EnablePSRemoting.ps1:34 char:1
>   + & $PSExec $Computer -u $User -p $Pass "ipconfig"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
>   Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
>   Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I then attempted to simply run PSExec from powershell directly, still no luck.

Comment: You should be using `Invoke-Command` and not PSExec

Comment: Invoke-Command requires remoting to be enabled, I believe, and if the script is to check if PS remoting is enabled, it's not exactly possible to use Invoke-Command, is it?

Comment: It requires winrm..... which is configured by group policy.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I'm with david how can I use invoke-command on a remote machine with psremoting disabled? I'm trying to copy a batch file that will enable psremoting on the specified remote machines.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I just tried 

`invoke-command {psexec \\Server1 -u Domain\Admin -p Pa$$w0rd ipconfig}`

still nothing

Comment: You use `Invoke-Command` in place of psexec.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I could use Copy-Item to copy file. Could I use Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -Scriptblock {start-process C:\mybat.bat} -Credentials Admin to execute batch file?

Comment: @Colyn1337
Wait that won't work. How am I to execute the file on the remote machine?

Comment: Not to be pendantic, but the examples you have posted only have (1) forward slash. Have you tried the same commands with (2) hacks?

Comment: @Get-HomeByFiveOClock yes I have....nice catch though

Comment: @Get-HomeByFiveOClock...hmmm...actually my posts has \\ but not showing up...must be some formatting issue. Added additional \ (for total of 3) now shows \\

Comment: There is a switch to accept the eula of ps exec.  Could that be getting in the way?

Comment: @TimAlexander I've already accpeted EULA but I tried using the acceptEula switch in my command still nothing

Comment: Running psexec from powershell needs some non obvious character escaping. I cannot write a proper answer right now, but you can easily google a couple of instructions out there detailing how to do it.

Comment: ErikE - that was sort-of what I was alluding to as well. My guess is it's either some of the aformentioned non-obvious character escaping or it may have something to do with Powershell not handling running certain commands which will start a new executable (meant to be run within the command line prompt i.e try running WMIC via powershell_ise)

Comment: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/10/02/using-powershell-and-psexec-to-invoke-expressions-on-remote-computers/

Comment: @ErikE
Update: The script works if I log in as 'admin' and remove -u [user] and -p [password]...though I would really like to be able to specify the user.

Comment: @TimAlexander 
Update: The script works if I log in as 'admin' and remove -u [user] and -p [password]...though I would really like to be able to specify the user.

Comment: @Get-HomeByFiveOClock 
Update: The script works if I log in as 'admin' and remove -u [user] and -p [password]...though I would really like to be able to specify the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Start-Process -Filepath "$PSExec" -ArgumentList "\\$computer -u $user -p $pass $command"`does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the script, you need the double backslash before the computername:
    & \\$PSExec $Computer -u $User -p $Pass "ipconfig"

In the list of attempts directly in PowerShell, if that's the actual password, then the double dollar sign was interpreted as the last token of the last command.

Comment: Double backslash is before computer name in actual script. Updated post to reflect this. Also, 'Pa$$w0rd' is not the password

Answer (score -1):

I tried using this and it seems to work when using the Syntax

```
.\Psexe.exe \\$Computer
```

With the leading dot in place.

Comment: Correction
.\Psexe.exe \\$Computer